# How to list the pre-installed Python packages on IBM's Spark service

Tags: python, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, data-science-experience, watson-studio

*Update August 2019: This question is no longer relevant. It refers to a retired Apache Spark as a Service offering. Current Spark backends in Watson Studio use a different technology.*

In a Python notebook, I can execute `!pip freeze` to get a list of installed packages. But the result is an empty list, or shows only a few packages that I installed myself. Until a few weeks ago, the command would return a list of all the packages, including those pre-installed by IBM. How can I get the full list now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!PIP_USER= pip freeze`

IBM sets the environment variable PIP_USER to enable the `--user` option by default. That's because many users forgot to specify that option for `pip install`. Unfortunately, this also enables the option for `pip freeze`, where it might not be desired. Therefore, you have to override the default option to get the full list of installed packages.

Alternative ways to ignore default options from environment variables:

- `!pip freeze --isolated`
- `!env -i pip freeze`

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I thought my acceptance was implied by answering my own question :-)